# How to convert a React.Component as a pure function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, eslint

Eslint suggest me to use a pure fiction instead of a react component.

I use eslint in airbnb config.

> error  Component should be written as a pure function  react/prefer-stateless-function

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/profilsetting" element={<ProfilSetting />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function App {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/profilsetting" element={<ProfilSetting />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

or...

```
const App = () =>  (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="/profilsetting" element={<ProfilSetting />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
```

No need to use a Class component since there is no state in the component. With hooks you don't need to use Class anyway, but could be a preference. Even before hooks function components were preferred if there was no state in the component

Answer (score 0):

Add constructor into it and use React.component after extends keyword